# Unable to install pip on windows for python 3.6.1 version

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am getting the below error while using the command:

python get-pip.py

Error:

```
c:\Python>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa0q8wceq\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", l
ine 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa0q8wceq\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.
py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa0q8wceq\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_res
ources\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "c:\Python\lib\plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "c:\Python\lib\xml\parsers\expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: `pip` comes installed with Windows Python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that pip comes with python 3 and up. If you have troubles running only "pip" from the terminal i'd recommend you try: `python -m pip ...`

Comment: c:\Python>python -m pip
c:\Python\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: Im getting this in command prompt: c:\Python>python -m pip
c:\Python\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: Maybe try downloading pip from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/)?

Comment: If possible please give me link to the file. I am not able to figure it out. I am new to python. Using it to run some codes on machine learning.

Comment: @Rahul I don't understand your problem, I provided you a link where you can download the file needed.

Comment: I checked that link. The file listed there is pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl .. and this file is already there in path C:\Python\Lib\ensurepip\_bundled in my local setup... Thats why I requested to give the file. is it the same file. If so then it has in my local setup. But still pip is not working.

Comment: @Rahul I'm afraid I can't help you then. But good luck installing pip'!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the 'Alternative instructions' from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?answertab=active#tab-top) post.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Better to close as  a duplicate instead of a link-only answer.

Comment: I don't know how to close as duplicate so I just give him a possible answer.